# CSS styling nav elements

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to recreate this menu for some time now only I have had little success. I am not inexperienced with CSS however this problem has left me stumped. I tried inspecting the page only I can't seem to find the secret to creating the "wavy" corners of each link. Any help you can give is much appreciated. Here is a link to the site:

http://css-tricks.com

Thanks in advance, and good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]CSS-TRICKS is using an inline SVG for each tab, the color is set using CSS.

Here is a good introduction by Chris himself: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Here is a more detailed description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: Thank you for providing links to where I can learn the svg strategy. I plan to study up!

Answer (score 2):

He's using SVG here, if you expand it you can see the root code
`<path id="shape-tab" d="M100,25C79.568,25,84.815,0,59.692,0H11.149C5.027,0,0,4.634,0,10.385V25"></path>`

Answer (score 0):

You could always try out the tutorials they have going at css-tricks as well
http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: I did find this resource on my own however I couldn't figure out how they did it for their menu. SVG's were the answer I was looking for but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Chris has used svgs to attain those shapes.

You could also use background images to achieve the same layout. Create a sprite containing the images for the first menu-item image and the subsequent menu-item image. Make the menu items `position: relative` and provide them with a z-index values to overlap on each menu item.

Comment: Thank you for the possible alternative... I will keep it in mind!